# How to cancel a function which is called by a background worker?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a background worker which calls a function within a separate class. This process may be required to be canceled at any time  via a button click from the front end. I have tried using CancelAsync() but this has no effect. The cofunds_downloadfiles is the function which i am calling. How do i go about canceling the process?

TIA.

```
Private Sub btnProcessdld_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProcessdld.Click

    Dim cfHelper As New CoFundsHelper

    If btnProcessdld.Text = "Process" Then
        btnProcessdld.Text = "Cancel"

        If chkDailyFiles.Checked = False And chkWeeklyFiles.Checked = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select which files you want to download")
        Else

            lblProgress.Text = "Processing...if you are downloading weekly files this may take a few minutes"
            uaWaitdld.AnimationEnabled = True
            uaWaitdld.AnimationSpeed = 50
            uaWaitdld.MarqueeAnimationStyle = MarqueeAnimationStyle.Continuous
            uaWaitdld.MarqueeMarkerWidth = 60

            _backGroundWorkerdld = New BackgroundWorker
            _backGroundWorkerdld.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
            _backGroundWorkerdld.RunWorkerAsync()

        End If

    ElseIf btnProcessdld.Text = "Cancel" Then
        btnProcessdld.Text = "Process"
        _backGroundWorkerdld.CancelAsync()
        uaWaitdld.AnimationEnabled = False

    End If

Private Sub StartProcessdld(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles _backGroundWorkerdld.DoWork

    Dim cfHelper As New CoFundsHelper
    cfHelper.ConnString = PremiumConnectionString
    Dim dateValue As String

    Dim weekly As Boolean = False
    Dim daily As Boolean = False

    If dtePicker.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        dateValue = Format(dtePicker.Value, "yyyyMMdd")

        If chkWeeklyFiles.Checked = True Then
            weekly = True
        End If
        If chkDailyFiles.Checked = True Then
            daily = True
        End If

        cfHelper.Cofunds_DownloadFiles(dateValue, weekly, daily)

    Else
        Throw (New Exception("Date Field is empty"))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do the following:

- in the DoWork sub, test for `cancellationpending` property
- if it's true then you simply do not call that function and maybe put `e.Cancelled = true` then check this in the RunWorkerCompleted and decide what you have to do.
- if you need to cancel it, simply make a `Stop()` sub in your class that does exactly that - stops the procedure. Then, you simply need to invoke it like

  ```
  Me.Invoke(Sub()
            myClass.Stop()
         End Sub)
  ```
- you may need to suspend the background worker until the call from your main thread has returned. You do this using semaphores:  `Private chk As New Semaphore(1,1,"checking1")`  You put this as a global variable to both your main thread and the background worker.
- in the backgroundworker_doWork you use the semaphore like `chk.WaitOne()` AFTER the line that need to execute.
- in the method of your class, when it has finished with computing you put `a.Release`

The semaphore is only needed if you need to make sure you wait for a result. It kind of defeats the purpose of multithreading but you can perform other actions in the worker before waiting for the main thread (like starting another thread with something else etc).

Other than that invoking a stop method should be enough. Sorry that i haven't had time to analyze your code but i hope i put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

`CancelAsync` doesn't actually do the cancelling of the worker (is just sets `CancellationPending = True`) so you basically have to check the state of the BackGroundWorker in your function:

```
Do While Not worker.CancellationPending
    'some long running process
Loop
```

I have found that this is not 100% reliable however, so it may be safer to use a cancelled flag of your own.

Comment: I understand your logic, but as the code is in a separate class how will it even be able to see the status of the backgroundworker?

Comment: You could pass a reference to the worker to your class but that is messy and the OO police will throw away the keys if you do that.

Comment: You could create a worker object in your class and expose a method to start and cancel the class which in turn starts and cancels the worker